# Receiving "Invalid policy document or request headers!"

Tags: amazon-s3, fine-uploader, amazon-iam

I am attempting to upload a file to S3 following the examples provided in your documentation and source files. Unfortunately, I'm receiving the following errors when attempting an upload:

> [Fine Uploader 5.3.2] Invalid policy document or request headers!
>
> [Fine Uploader 5.3.2] Policy signing failed.  Invalid policy document
>   or request headers!

I found a few posts on here with similar errors, but those solutions didn't help me.

Here is my jQuery:

```
<script>
    $('#fine-uploader').fineUploaderS3({
        request: {
            endpoint: "http://mybucket.s3.amazonaws.com",
            accessKey: "changeme"
        },
        signature: {
        endpoint: "endpoint.php"
        },
        uploadSuccess: {
            endpoint: "success.html"
        },        
        template: 'qq-template'
    });
</script>
```

(Please note that I changed the keys/bucket names for security sake.)

I used your endpoint-cors.php as a model and have included the portions that I modified here:

```
require 'assets/aws/aws-autoloader.php';
use Aws\S3\S3Client;

// These assume you have the associated AWS keys stored in
// the associated system environment variables
$clientPrivateKey = $_ENV['changeme'];
// These two keys are only needed if the delete file feature is enabled
// or if you are, for example, confirming the file size in a successEndpoint
// handler via S3's SDK, as we are doing in this example.
$serverPublicKey = $_ENV['AWS_SERVER_PUBLIC_KEY'];
$serverPrivateKey = $_ENV['AWS_SERVER_PRIVATE_KEY'];

// The following variables are used when validating the policy document
// sent by the uploader. 
$expectedBucketName = $_ENV['mybucket'];
// $expectedMaxSize is the value you set the sizeLimit property of the 
// validation option. We assume it is `null` here. If you are performing
// validation, then change this to match the integer value you specified
// otherwise your policy document will be invalid.
// http://docs.fineuploader.com/branch/develop/api/options.html#validation-option
$expectedMaxSize = (isset($_ENV['S3_MAX_FILE_SIZE']) ? $_ENV['S3_MAX_FILE_SIZE'] : null);
```

I also changed this:

```
// Only needed in cross-origin setups
function handleCorsRequest() {
// If you are relying on CORS, you will need to adjust the allowed domain here.
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://test.mydomain.com');
}
```

The POST seems to work:

> POST http://test.mydomain.com/somepath/endpoint.php 200 OK
>         318ms

...but that's where the success ends.

I think part of the problem is that I'm not sure what to enter for "clientPrivateKey". Is that my "Secret Access Key" I set up with IAM?

And I'm definitely unclear on where I get the serverPublicKey and serverPrivateKey. Where am I generating a key-pair on the S3? I've combed through the docs, and perhaps I missed it.

Thank you in advance for your assistance!

Answer (score 0):

First off, you are using endpoint-cors.php in a non-CORS environment. Communication between the browser and your endpoint appears to be same-origin, based on the URL of your signature endpoint. Switch to the endpoint.php example.

Regarding your questions about the keys, you should have create two distinct IAM users: one for client-side operations (heavily restricted) and one for server-side operations (an admin user). For each user, you'll have an access key (public) and a secret key (private). You always supply Fine Uploader with your client-side public key, and use your client-side private key to sign requests server-side. To perform other, more restricted operations (such as deleting files), you should use your server user keys.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I switched to the endpoint.php example per your instructions, filled in the environment variables as before... but I'm still getting the same exact errors: "Invalid policy document or request headers!" and "Policy signing failed.  Invalid policy document or request headers!" What additional information can I provide?

Comment: Several days ago (Nov 6), I purchased a license for this product as well as a technical support ticket for assistance with this issue. I have not heard anything back, not even an acknowledgement of the ticket. What do I need to do for my ticket to get noticed? Thank you very much.

Comment: @mrbranden Your message was caught in our spam filter. Responding to it now.